# How to show last 10 min old records from mysql

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a MySQL database having column **time** containing Unix timestamp like **1482858013**.

Now I want to make a MySQL query which should show only the last five minute old records from the database. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table is called `ata_table`, then query would be something like:

```
select
  *
from data_table
where
    `time` > unix_timestamp()-300;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_SUB()` to get the time 5 minutes ago, and `UNIX_TIMSTAMP()` to convert that to a numeric timestamp.

```
WHERE time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE))
```

Comment: Sir what to do if i want to show 24 hours old records or 30 days old records

Comment: Change the interval to whatever you want. `INTERVAL 24 HOUR`, `INTERVAL 30 DAY`. What's the problem?

Comment: Can i get all records from midnight to till now pertaining to my local time?

Comment: The `CURDATE()` function returns the current date. When you compare it with a datetime, the missing time defaults to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000,'%Y-%M-%d) as timestamp FROM table
    WHERE timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE))
    Order by timestamp desc
```