# get timestamp minimum and maximum value for a given month in PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

**What i have:**

I have a php - mysql - jquery/ajax scheduler with dynamically loaded user-tasks. In order to display a user-task start and end time i store the values as an `unix timestamp` in my `MYSQl database`.

For example:

```
Task start: 1599026400 = 2020-09-02 08:00:00
Task end: 1599057000 = 2020-09-02 16:30:00
```

In order to get all task in the database for one month i need the minimum and maximum `timestamp` of that specific month.

```
Min date: 1598911200 = 2020-09-01 00:00:00 
Max date: 1601503199 = 2020-09-30 23:59:59
```

**The problem:**
I am searching for the most clean/fast way to fetch this data.

```
$result = time();                             // current timestamp (is created by a jquery date-picker)
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $result));    // create a new date to remove the original time (H:i:s)
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-01 H:i:s', $time));  // display first day of month, time = 00:00:00
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-t H:i:s', $time)) + 86399; // display last day of month (add 86399 seconds = 23:59:59)
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this result?

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41349195/how-to-show-last-10-min-old-records-from-mysql

Comment: This question you are referring to is about subtracting 5-10 minutes from a timestamp. The referred question is also about MYSQL and not PHP.

Comment: Please refer to this. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-eomonth-function/#:~:text=The%20EOMONTH()%20function%20returns,(start_date%20%5B%2C%20offset%5D%20)%3B

Comment: Did you time your query while fetching the data older than "month before" and younger "month after". This way you don't need any php calculation for the timestamps?

Comment: would it not be more flexible to store your times as a DateTime (the Mysql kind)? Those are readable by humans and your query can be build in a more comprehensive way:
WHERE yourColumn BETWEEN '2020-09-01' AND '2020-10-01. It would even be simple to extract only those records where yourColumn refers to a Tuesday. Unix timestamps will bring you a lot of work. And sure, your question is not about this, but at some point you may get this kind of questions on your data, and then it could be to late to convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see other faster solution than just conversion from date stamp to Unix timestamp specifying first/last day of a month.

```
$month_start = strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00')); //1598911200
$month_end = strtotime(date('Y-m-t 23:59:59')); //1601503199
```

But in this case you get one notice. This converts date according to the server's timezone. So if you are in Europe/Berlin zone, timestamp will be +2 hours away from UTC. If you want to get UTC timestamp you must convert a timezone. You can do it with `date()` function but I prefer manipulating with `DateTime` object.

```
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00'), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$month_start_utc = $date->format('U'); //1598918400

$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-t 23:59:59'), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$month_end_utc = $date->format('U'); //1601510399
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way, don't need to add `86399` seconds:

```
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-01 00:00:00'));  // display first day of month, time = 00:00:00
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-t 23:59:59'));   // display last day & time of month, time = 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DateTime object to get the first and last day of the month:

```
$time = time(); // or whatever timestamp you want to use

$firstDayTime = (new \DateTime())
    ->setTimestamp($time)
    ->setTime(0, 0, 0)
    ->modify('first day of this month')
    ->format('U')
;

$lastDayTime = (new \DateTime())
    ->setTimestamp($time)
    ->setTime(23, 59, 59)
    ->modify('last day of this month')
    ->format('U')
;
```

Not sure if it's cleaner nor faster, though...

Comment: `DateTime` takes current time as default in constructor. You don't need to repeat it in `setTime()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several approaches and there you can find results:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd42088f7086a9986b1e295fb588f98714fddf2e

fastest way was:

```
function func_5(){
  $month=date('n');
  $year=date('Y');
  $start=strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01 00:00:00');
  $number_of_days=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);
  return [$start, $start+$number_of_days*86400-1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the provided answers only give the solution to the current month. But if you'd want the min/max for any given month, I'd manipulate a date using `DateInterval`

```php
function min_max_timestamp(int $year, int $month): array {
    $start = new DateTimeImmutable(date("$year-$month-01 00:00:00"), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $end = $start->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))
        ->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'));

    $month_start_utc = $start->format('U');
    $month_end_utc = $end->format('U');

    return [$month_start_utc, $month_end_utc];
}

list($min, $max) = min_max_timestamp(2020, 9);
```

You could skip the `->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'))` step if you changed you SQL-query to use less than `start >= 'first of month' AND start < 'first of next month'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use MySQL for that and only pass the month for your query.

See working example here: https://paiza.io/projects/pvZ6tl2mRE1FJaweyT37Yw?language=mysql

This way you don't need any calculation in PHP.

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE task (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  start timestamp NOT NULL,
  end timestamp NOT NULL
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO task VALUES (1, '2020-09-01 00:00:01', '2020-09-01 20:00:01');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (2, '2020-09-15 00:00:01', '2020-09-16 12:00:01');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (3, '2020-09-30 00:00:01', '2020-09-30 23:59:59');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (4, '2020-08-31 23:00:01', '2020-08-31 23:59:01');
INSERT INTO task VALUES (5, '2020-10-01 00:00:01', '2020-10-02 01:00:01');

-- fetch some values
SELECT * FROM task WHERE MONTH(start) = 9 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three ways of doing this.
Using `PHP` [`Date/Time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) functions

```
$date = '2020-09-02 08:00:00';
$dateParts = date_parse($date);
$date = $dateParts['year']."-".$dateParts['month']."-01 00:00:00";
$startDate = date_create($date);
$endDate = date_sub(date_add(date_create($date), date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 month')),date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 second'));
print_r(['start' => date_timestamp_get($startDate), 'end' => date_timestamp_get($endDate)]);
Array
(
    [start] => 1598943600
    [end] => 1601535599
)
```

**OR**

by using `MySQL` [`Date/Time`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) functions

```
SELECT DATE_SUB('2020-09-02 08:00:00',INTERVAL CONCAT(DAY('2020-09-02 08:00:00')-1,' ',HOUR('2020-09-02 08:00:00'),':',MINUTE('2020-09-02 08:00:00'),':',SECOND('2020-09-02 08:00:00')) DAY_SECOND), DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB('2020-09-02 08:00:00',INTERVAL CONCAT(DAY('2020-09-02 08:00:00')-1,' ',HOUR('2020-09-02 08:00:00'),':',MINUTE('2020-09-02 08:00:00'),':',SECOND('2020-09-02 08:00:00')) DAY_SECOND), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 SECOND);

OUTPUT
2020-09-01 00:00:00  | 2020-09-30 23:59:59
```

**OR**

by doing the exact same thing client-side and send the timestamp using ajax not the date. I think in this case it is not something you want since it would need more changes in your code as a total (front-end, back-end). Nevertheless here is a similar way using `Javascript`.

```js
let pickDate = new Date('2020-09-02 08:01:32');
let startDate = new Date(pickDate.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+(pickDate.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-01");
startDate.setHours(-startDate.getTimezoneOffset()/60);
let endDate = new Date(startDate);
endDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()+1);
endDate.setSeconds(-1);
console.log([startDate,endDate]);
console.log([startDate.getTime()/1000,endDate.getTime()/1000]);
```

Comment: Terrible example of using DateTime object.

Comment: @Tajni if you mean that `TimeZone` should have been set yes it should. But on this case it is assumed that the `Date` that was stored in the database was done in such a way that respects the server-client `Timezone` difference that might exist. Thanks for the comment but i don't think it is a terrible example.

Comment: @Tajni I think your answer pre-existed when i started to write this answer. So i had to write something different don't you think?! How ethical would it be from my behalf to write an answer pretty similar like yours? I kind of thought that the point of having multiple answers in a question is to provide something different in each answer.

Comment: @Tajni as you wrote ***Having correct answers is the point of SO.***. Here is a correct answer http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94a137dc775bdb457790b3078d88fa09ade45fc9. I'm sorry you find it ***obscure***. The fact that you did not understand why the rest of the answers are there, does not mean that it is also not understood by other people that might read or have read the answer.

Comment: @Tajni this is taken from the question... ***I have a php - mysql - jquery/ajax scheduler with dynamically loaded user-tasks.***.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to continue it. This example is just a bad quality, shouldn't be recommended.

Comment: @Tajni for bad quality it performs nice... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4a36722991426d52b8e4f6677c5bc09d10692d4

Comment: @Tajni if you check closer on the 21 lines you refer, you will see that they are benchmarks of your snippet and mine. The performance is quite similar. Your snippet performs a little better by an amount of time < 0.1ms. I know it is more efficient but it is surely not a reason to consider something ***obscure***.

Answer (score -2):

By checking with microtime, your solution might not be neater, but it is quicker than using DateTime:

```
0.00017309188842773
0.00022792816162109
0.00019717216491699
0.00018095970153809
0.00018000602722168
0.00018596649169922
```

VS

```
0.00023007392883301
0.00029492378234863
0.00026392936706543
0.00024795532226562
0.00028395652770996
0.0002589225769043
```